# Where can I buy corn kernel for making popcorn?

Tags: shopping, popcorn

I want to home make popcorn by myself. Watching some video on youtube, I saw they are using a kind of kernel of corn. Are they different to what we eat normal corn? It seems that they are much smaller.

Comment: Popping corn is different to 'sweet' corn. It would be easier to suggest a location to buy it if you told us roughly where you were, i.e. your country.

Comment: Ask at your local supermarket for "popping corn", not popcorn. Usually in the snacks section

Comment: I am in Hong Kong.

Answer (score 1):

In the U.S., it's always sold dried and in whole kernels, unlike other kinds of corn, which are sold either whole (i.e., corn on the cob), as canned or frozen kernels, or dried and ground up as cornmeal or corn flour.

It's usually easy to find "microwave popcorn" at any supermarket, which is a handful of popcorn and some oil and flavorings inside a paper bag that is designed to be put into the microwave. Loose popcorn is less common, but still readily available if you know where to look. There's also little foil frying pans with a similar mixture to what is in the microwave bags, that you can cook on the stovetop, but those are rare these days.

Answer (score 1):

There is a special kind of corn used just for poping. You should be able to get this at your local market. I have seen many varietys of specialized poping corn from online distrubutors though. A buddy of mine bought some from [here](http://www.popcornlovers.com/shopcontent.asp?type=Where%20To%20Buy).

Sweet corn is different from pop corn due to pop corn having a extremely tough shell. The shell lets steam build up inside until it EXPLODES!

Answer (score 1):

Yes is different from normal corn.  Gets hot with oil and small water inside makes corn pop.

http://global.rakuten.com/en/store/caramelcafe/item/p_cot1002food005/

Cost is ¥2,056 for 8 pound/3.63 Kilogram.  Will last very long time.

再见

[Please do not edit for clarity]

Answer (score 1):

Ask at your local supermarket for "popping corn", not popcorn. Usually in the snacks section or whole foods section

In Hong Kong try Edens or Little Giant

On the mainland be careful "popping corn" is a pyrotechnic device !

To make popcorn you don't need any special equipment, just a saucepan and a little practise

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find it anywhere South Asian (Indian) groceries are available. Its been some time since I was last in HK but I think you could try the Kowloon area.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon is almost always a good starting point for "where can I get....?" questions: [Amazon Popcorn](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=popcorn&x=0&y=0), you will probably pay more for shipping but it should get there. (I don't know of any restrictions on importing popcorn, but that doesn't mean there aren't any.)

For home popcorn production you can't beat a [Whirley Pop](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=stripbooks&field-keywords=whirly%20pop&x=0&y=0) popper. Any of these is a great way to go. *(I don't normally endorse brands, but this is an exception.)*

If you want to learn more about popcorn then the is the book ["Popcorn" by Patrick Evans-Hylton](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1570615799)